# Python when writing to Excel

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy, xlsxwriter

It is taking a long time to execute this code. I have a table called `coilid` with about 3000 rows. I want the program go to coilid, see the date of process, and compare with retifica and if it's in the range determined, so i want they export some retifica cells.  It's for all rows in coilid.

```
import pandas as pd

retifica = pd.read_excel('C:\Arquivoparamim.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')
retifica = retifica.sort_values(by=['Data Retífica'], ascending=True)

coilid = pd.read_excel('C:\Arquivoparamim.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha2')
coilid = coilid.sort_values(by=['DT_START'], ascending=True)

match=pd.DataFrame()

for x in range (coilid.shape[0]):
    for y in range (retifica.shape[0]):
        if (coilid.iloc[x,2]>retifica.iloc[y,16])&(coilid.iloc[x,2]<retifica.iloc[y,18]):
            matchaux = [coilid.iloc[x],retifica.iloc[y]]
        else:
            matchaux = [coilid.iloc[x]]
            match=match.append(matchaux)
        break
    

match.to_excel('Libraries\Pictures\aline.xlsx')
```

I was expecting the program to make a comparison between coilid id [DT_START] with the info "Data de entrada e "Data de Saída in retifica. If coilid was between these datas, then it would return into a excel sheet the value of coilid row concatenated with ret  and cilindro and in retifica file.

Retifica row
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/177KL.png)

coilid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgm0m.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is essential that you vectorise the code when dealing with these many rows. You can use `between` method to create a boolean mask to indicate whether each element of the `DT_START` column is between the corresponding elements of the `Data de entrada` and `Data de Saída` columns. Maybe this can help

```
# Load dataframes
retifica = pd.read_excel('C:\Arquivoparamim.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')
coilid = pd.read_excel('C:\Arquivoparamim.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha2')

# Sort dataframes by dates
retifica = retifica.sort_values(by=['Data Retífica'], ascending=True)
coilid = coilid.sort_values(by=['DT_START'], ascending=True)

# Perform the comparison using vectorized operations
mask = coilid['DT_START'].between(retifica['Data Entrada'].values, retifica['Data Saída'].values, inclusive=False)
coilid_filtered = coilid.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
retifica_filtered = retifica.loc[mask.values].reset_index(drop=True)

# Concatenate dataframes and select columns of interest
match = pd.concat([coilid_filtered, retifica_filtered[['ret', 'cilindro']]], axis=1)

match.to_excel('Libraries\Pictures\aline.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: It returned me this ERROR: KeyError: 'Data de entrada'

Comment: i can't see the error!

Comment: I posted as answer of my question.

Comment: Could it be that the keys (header) are not `Data de entrada` but `Data Entrada`. Same goes for `Data saida`. You can edit this in the code.

Comment: it almost loaded, but now if exibing another error. it's because the lenghts of the colluns are not the same. so, i need to make a loop to check if coil id date is inside the data entrada e data saída.